# How to develop a web application for AWS practice Labs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I would like to develop a web application for AWS practice labs where I can create 
users and allow them to practice their AWS knowledge with live labs just like https://qwiklabs.com/

In this application, according to labs I need to provision AWS resources automatically as per the lab requirements and allow the user to complete the lab
with limited access.

So, Please share your suggestion, how can I do this whole setup with my AWS account.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at how QwikLabs provided their service early on when they first started offering services. Back then their IAM policies were not well written and I could see the resources that they were provisioning. I studied many of their CloudFormation templates. This is not true today as they have tightened everything very well.

1) They developed their own management system for managing users, payments, account access, etc.

2) They use CloudFormation with very tight IAM permissions to create the labs that you access. Via IAM policies they control what you can do and access. They also time you out and drop everything after a period of time. This is one of the better/best executions of CloudFormation that I have experienced.

Their setup is actually very well thought-out and executed.

Comment: Thank you, John for your valuable suggestion, it's really helpful to me.